# Nodejs, where do requests queue up if the node is busy?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

Say I have an express.js application that exposes an endpoint on `localhost:80/api`. Let's say the handler has to do synchronous operations (bad idea, I know). Now, let's say the rate at which node processes the requests is lower that the incoming request rate.

Obviously, an incoming request that finds node busy cannot be executed. Where do they end up waiting?